# How print a variable randomly in a list

Tags: python

For example:

```
import random
Bandit="B"
List=["","","",""]
```

Something like this:

```
import random
List=["","","",""]
List[i]='B'
for i in range(0,2):
    print(random.randint(List[i]))
```

Aka doesn't work

What I want it to print out using  for function like:

```
print["B","","B",""] or ["","B","","B"] and all the other combinations
```

Comment: In python I was making a game with randomly generated variables on lists and didn't know so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I can't work out whether you want the program to randomly place the bandit or have it randomly select between the two combinations? Went for the first of the two but if you want the later just say. Hope this helps :)

```
import random
numb = random.randint(0,3)
bandit = "B"
list = ["","","",""]
list[numb] = bandit
print(list)
```

Comment: How do you add another "B" into a list when it prints out

Answer (score 0):

i am not quite sure why do want to use random function, but since you know where you want 'B' to occur, you can.

```
List[i] = 'B'    # i is an integer, and it is where you want your thing to be
```

like

```
List[0] = 'B'    # 0 is where a list starts 
List[2] = 'B'
```

result

```
['B','','B','']
```

Comment: and a [https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html), links to python tutorial - data structure - list